# Is it common for controversial question to be removed from Hot Questions on network?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I just made a question that I knew it would end up being controversial due to the topics and my huge bias (which I cleaned up as best as I can), but I still want to reach as many people as possible to know the public consensus about the answers given, and what the "correct" way to handle this would be.

That being said, Why was my question removed from Hot Network Question ? Are mods just trying to limit exposure to a controversial topic ?

[Question Mentioned](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/194352/140150)

Comment: It looks like you linked to one of the answers instead of the question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is common.

The "Hot Questions" feature should be used used to attract other people that might be interested in workplace topics and asking or answering questions.

What it does with controversial topics of all kinds is that it attracts people interested in that specific topic that come to discuss that specific topic in comments. That is not the point of "Hot Questions" or this site in general.

That is why the option to remove a question from "Hot Network Questions" exists and we use it often when we feel that a question does not attract potential future users interested in this site, but potential flyby commenters.

I did not do it myself, since I try to not moderate questions I have an answer in, but I fully support the decision to do it and would have done the same on another question of the same sort.

It is the least invasive form of moderation since nothing is actually restricted, it is just not advertised any more.

Comment: Thank you for clarifiying, aprecciate it.

Answer (score 5):

The gender questions tend to be of limited use in my opinion. They make no sense in my locale and most of the World. And while they do attract traffic, it's not positive traffic. It attracts bigotry from both sides, and I think discrimination should be discouraged, including that against heterosexual and religious people. At the end of the day your question was unlikely to be a common workplace issue people need to deal with.

So there's no point showcasing our site with it and I support the decision to remove it from HNQ.

Comment: In my locale, they are so rare that no one has a clue how to react too. Thanks for the clarification